# What is the default behavior of clang-format being called without -style=file option?

Tags: formatting, clang, llvm-clang, clang-format

Does it take `-style=LLVM` or `-style=file` as the default one? 
Here is an example of the command, and I wonder how does it behave:
`clang-format-4.0 -i path/to/file/to/format.cpp`

Answer (score 4):

If `-style` is not specified, the default is `-style=file`. If no `.clang-format` file can be found, the default behavior is the same as `-style=LLVM`. Unfortunately, the [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) doesn't specify this.

Comment: I tried improving the documentation in https://reviews.llvm.org/rG1ab37d996ce376129fa435b63ca50246cc8c2f8d . https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html is updated with that change by now. It now explicitly says that `-style=file` is the default.